# WebFocus - is there a free/open source alternative?

Tags: asp.net, olap

What is a good free/open source alternative to [WebFOCUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebFOCUS)?

Is there an ASP.NET way of getting info from an OLAP cube?

**Update:** I chose Magnus Smith's answer as the correct one, but [Alexmac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145322/webfocus-is-there-a-freeopen-source-alternative#145467) was also very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out, MDX is horrible - nothing like SQL even though it looks like it is.

You can get a .NET control to show OLAP data on a web page. Our company tested one from Dundas that was OK. I never got involved though so I don't know if it was brilliant or merely serviceable.
http://www.dundas.com/Gallery/Chart/NET/index.aspx?ImgGroup=OLAP

We gave up on SQL Reporting Services as it was not suitable for Internet usage (fine on Intranet though).

Comment: I don't think Dundas do a free version, other than one that can only be used for evaluation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of free analytical suite. But what is it you are trying to accomplish?

You can query an OLAP cube by using MDX queries with ADO.net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144785.aspx

You can then bind the results to a datagrid for example. MDX is a little like SQL but be careful as it has several syntax differences. I think Excel has a query tool you can use to graphically construct your queries which can be helpful.

On a related note look into SQL reporting services. With SQL express you can use a cut down version of sql reporting services that may accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Reporting services is something that we've looked into, but we also need Report Builder - to enable our users to build their own reports on demand. We need them to be able to do that on the web - is that possible using ADO.net?

Comment: SQL reporting services also includes a report builder component that allows user to build their own reports. This is only in the full version of SQL through. Take a look at: http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3520116

Comment: If you want to show OLAP data on the Internet (as opposed to an intranet) you need a 'web-facing' licence for SQL Server I believe, which adds to the cost.